# AngularJS: Re order Array by Parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to re sort an array, placing the parent first and followed their children:

P.D: I'm using angularjs.

These well:

```
[
{id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0},
{id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0},
{id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1},
{id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 1},
{id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 0},
{id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 0},
{id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 2},
{id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2}
]
```

You must be so:

```
[
{id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0},
{id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1},
{id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 1},
{id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0},
{id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 2},
{id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2},
{id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 0},
{id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 0},
]
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't require angular.  You can do this with the .sort() functionality in javascript.

```
array.sort(function(a,b) {
    var aString, bString;
    if (a.parent==0) {
        aString = ('000' + a.id).slice(-3) + '.000';
    } else {
        aString = ('000' + a.parent).slice(-3) + '.' 
                + ('000' + a.id).slice(-3);
    }
    if (b.parent==0) {
        bString = ('000' + b.id).slice(-3) + '.000';
    } else {
        bString = ('000' + b.parent).slice(-3) + '.' 
                + ('000' + b.id).slice(-3);
    }

    if (aString==bString) return 0;
    if (aString<bString) return -1;
    return 1;
})
```

My guess from your post is that an object with parent==0 is a parent (and has no other parent), so you want to sort those by id.  In between each parent, you want all the objects where parent == id of the parent object.

To do this we can create a string representing the sort order.  The string will consist of the zero-filled parent id (or the object id, if it has no parents), followed by the zero-filled object id (or 000, if it has not parents).

The sort values (aString) would in this case be: '001.000', '001.003', '001.004', '002.000', ...

As implemented above, it will only work for ids < 1000 and only if there aren't any grandchildren.  This can be generalized to those situations, if necessary.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Another option, which might be easier to understand if you can be sure the IDs are going to be numbers:

```
array.sort(function(a,b) {
    var aVal, bVal;
    var m = 10000

    if (a.parent==0) aVal = a.id * m;
    else aVal = a.parent * m + a.id;

    if (b.parent==0) bVal = b.id * m;
    else bVal = b.parent * m + b.id;

    return aVal-bVal;
})
```

Comment: I require re order the parent post array ID, putting the father in front of the children.

Comment: @NJavierRomero, thanks for the comment.  I believe I understood your question.  The answer I give above works according to your example.  Is there a problem with it?  I have a working [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/beartums/sqjgj6Lv/3/)

Comment: Excellent.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood your example.

But I suggest you to sort JSON array in 2 steps.

**Step 1:**

convert the JSON into Object:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(jsonArr);
```

**Step 2:**

Sort the array according to what you need:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.parent < b.parent)
    return -1;
  else if (a.parent > b.parent)
    return 1;
  else 
    return 0;
}

arr.sort(compare);
```

Comment: I require re order the parent post array ID, putting the father in front of the children